# Not able to install the python-module numpy

Tags: python, windows, numpy

After hours of trying I'm still not able to install numpy. I READ LOTS OF HINTS, ANSWERS USW. BUT IT DOESN'T HELP.
Furthermore I have windows 7, 32 bit, Python 27.

What I did:

1. download     `numpy-1.10.2.zip`:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/
2. unzip it
3. start the windows command prompt and input:
   `cd C:\Users\myname\Desktop\numpy-1.10.2`
4. now it appears:
   `C:\Users\myname\Desktop\numpy-1.10.2>`
5. I input:
   `python setup.py install`
6. and there appears an error:

   ```
   Running from numpy source directory.
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 263, in <module>
       setup_package()
   File "setup.py", line 246, in setup_pa
       import setuptools
   ImportError: No module named setuptools
   ```

I hope somebody can help me or even better IS THERE NOT EASIER WAY TO INSTALL NUMPY OR OTHER MODULES??

Comment: Easier way - use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) (or another distribution).

Answer (score 2):

Building numpy from source on windows is non-trivial. Best use official binaries (http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.10.2/) or Gohlke binaries (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) or a distribution like Anaconda or Canopy or WinPython.

Comment: Building basic NumPy isn't hard on Windows, at least not for 2.7 or 3.5 (3.4 is a chore). Install [C++ compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) or [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions) for 3.5. Then use pip to build a wheel. However, Microsoft doesn't distribute a Fortran compiler to build LAPACK, so the resulting NumPy lacks accelerated linear algebra. You need the MinGW or Intel toolchain for Fortran. Save yourself the hassle and get a pre-built package as ev-br suggests.

Comment: thanks for the quick answert.

i still cant install numpy. for me it is necessary that you explain it more detailed. best you guess i have no idea from installing modules!

so to your first hint: i used the official binaries (see my link above) but it doesnt work...

and maybe you can tell me how Anaconda can help me to install numpy?
I don’t have any idea how to install it, because i am the opposite of a profi ;-), can you give me a little bit exacter answers??

Comment: Your link was that you downloaded the source and tried compiling it. For that, you need what e.g. @eryksun said. It's simpler to download an exe installer, run that and follow the prompts.

Comment: Hallelujah, finally there is a simple way, exe installer sounds great :-D
But I could not find one, maybe somebody have a hint (or even better a link) where I can download a exe-file which installs numpy??

Comment: Now it has worked :-D, I could find an exe-file thx for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the setuptools package as well. See [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

A more easy way to install python packages is using pip, which resolves package dependencies automatically. See [here](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/#use-pip-for-installing). Pip should be included in your python installation if you use a recent version.

You should succeed by calling `pip install numpy`.

Comment: That almost certainly won't work - the OP would need to have a working toolchain in order build the C extensions, which is not straightforward to set up on Windows.