# Scipy package not installing using pip

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am not able to install scipy on my machine with python 2.7

```
pip install scipy
```

It always comes up with the following error

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the message says, You need functioning blas/lapack, which you need to install separately. How to do that depends on the operating system you're on.

Comment: Can you please help me with how to install it? It would be really helpful of you.

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: On windows, the basic suggestion is to use prebuilt packages (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579089/not-able-to-install-the-python-module-numpy/34580195#34580195).

Comment: Numpy is installed on my system but installing Scipy is giving issues. I am not able to get how to get through this. I am stuck with this issue from last 3 days. Seriously need your help.

Comment: Compiling SciPy on windows  is more difficult than numpy (for one, you need a Fortran compiler). Like I'm saying, best use prebuilt binaries ( official binaries, Gohlke wheels, Anaconda, Canopy, WinPython)